# Passing string from form to new form name

Tags: string, vb.net, forms, winforms

Thank you all for your kind help. I have three forms that require the string name inputted from NameForm to pass to Form1 and renaming Form1 to whatever name is placed on the textbox.

Then in Form1 is renamed JOHN DOE, I will have various text boxes to input data.  After I hit calculate, it will pass all the data to Form3 and renaming Form3 to JOHN DOE. I have all the code written and functioning properly pass the data from FORM1 to Form3 except it is not passing the students name from NameForm and renaming Form1 and Form3. Below is my code for NameForm which is the basic form to type students name. If there is more code needed I will post it. I do not want to post all the code and risk down voted.

```
Public Class NameForm

   Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

        Dim name As New Form1()
        name.StringPass = Form1.Text
        name.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub NameForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Focus()
        Me.BringToFront()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `I do not want to post all the code and risk down voted.` - You never need to post _everything_. You should only post as much code as one would need to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `I do not want to post all the code and risk down voted.`  If you were really concerned about DVs you'd read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only need to declare a **Public access level** to the class. (Thanks to Enigmativity for the correction)

```
Public Class NameForm
    Public studentName As String

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

         Dim name As New Form1()
         name.Text = studentName
         name.Show()

     End Sub

     Private Sub NameForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

         Me.Focus()
         Me.BringToFront()
         Me.Hide()

     End Sub

End Class
```

If you want to call the global variable from other class:
*for example* and *in case you need it*

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        TextBox1.Text = NameForm.studentName

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It would be better to use a public property - Properties are more flexible - they can be databound and you can include code - such as validation before it is returned etc.

Comment: There are no global variables in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the `New` method on the form you want to pass the value to:

`Form1`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnPass_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPass.Click

        Dim form As New Form2(TextBox1.Text)
        form.Show()

    End Sub

End Class
```

`Form2`:

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        Label1.Text = value

    End Sub

End Class
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help. Bugs example was able to help me resolve the code. Thanks again.